# Java app sometimes lock up in Netbeans : D3D Screen Updater, Object.wait, how to fix?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, locking

My Java Swing application will lock up 30% of the time when I run it from Netbeans, so I used the debug function to "Debug File", I suspended all other threads, and found the ones that most likely caused the problem, they are :

```
<1> AWT-EventQueue-0
<2> D3d Screen Updater [ More likely ]
```

But when I clicked on it, it said : "Object.wait / Hidden Source Calls / D3dScreenUpdateManager.run.419 / Thread.run:619

It didn't point to where in my app, the problem was, what can I do to fix it ? I don't know where the problem is in my app.

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freezing of a GUI is usually caused by blocking the Event Dispatch Thread. Long running tasks should execute on a separate Thread.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more inforamtion and for solutions.

Comment: I thought I've taken care of this problem in all my apps, but after looking carefully, it was exactly this problem, it's an old program, somehow fell through the cracks. Thanks.